# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails": In snapshot (Gemfile.lock): rails (= 4.2.7.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading to openproject lastest version 6, however while running bundle install, I am getting the following error:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 4.2.7.1)

In Gemfile:
    rails (>= 4.2.7.1, ~> 4.2.7)

```
health_check was resolved to 1.5.1, which depends on
  rails (>= 2.3.0)

openproject-translations was resolved to 6.0.5, which depends on
  rails (~> 4.2.3)

prototype-rails was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
  rails (~> 4.0)

rails-angular-xss was resolved to 0.2.0.pre.pre, which depends on
  rails (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0)

rails_autolink (~> 1.1.6) was resolved to 1.1.6, which depends on
  rails (> 3.1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Please try this. remove `Gemfile.lock` file and again execute `bundle install`

Comment: are you trying to upgrade your rails application ? from lower versions to 4.2.7.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure you specify the correct rails version in Gemfile

2- Remove Gemfile.lock `rm Gemfile.lock`

3- bundle install

Answer (score 0):

You have dependencies which are incompatible.

```
openproject-translations was resolved to 6.0.5, which depends on
  rails (~> 4.2.3)
```

This requires rails 4.2.x (where x >= 3)

```
rails-angular-xss was resolved to 0.2.0.pre.pre, which depends on
  rails (< 5.1, >= 5.0.0)
```

This requires rails 5.0.x  (`< 5.1, >= 5.0.0` could be simplified to `~> 5.0.0`)

Since `openproject-translations` requires Rails 4 and `rails-angular-xss` requires Rails 5 there is no way that bundle can resolve them.

You could try a different version (e.g. rolling back a recent change) of one or both of those gems.

Instead of the 0.2.0.pre.pre version of rails-angular-xss, try the latest release [0.1.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-angular-xss) which will work for your current version of Rails.